# 「周期的」と「定期的」はどう違いますか

Tags: word-choice

The dictionary tells me that they both mean "periodic" so I can't actually understand the difference.
Can someone help me?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

定期的 is usually about human and societal things. If something is not particularly associated with calendar months and years, like a natural phenomenon, 周期的 would be better.

"first weekday of every month" is more 定期的 than 周期的. "every 1 millisecond" is more 周期的 than 定期的.

It can be a matter of perspectives, though. When a scientist observes a human behavior, they might use 周期的.